# Are there any true homonyms in Esperanto?

Tags: nouns

Okay, I’m cheating a bit, since I already know about one true homonym in Esperanto: **radio** (meaning *radio* *or* *ray*). Do any others exist?

I’m looking for single word roots with divergent meanings, so no puns like *kol-ego ⁓ kolego*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sendube estas multaj. Jen [listo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonimo) el Vikipedio.

- eno (tio kio estas ene de io) - eno (japana monunuo)
- kubo (matematika figuro) - Kubo (lando)
- gama (rilate al gamo) - gama (greka litero)
- ĉar' (= ĉaro) - ĉar (pro tio ke)
- koro (organo) - koro (mezurunuo.
- golfo (akva areo) - golfo (sporto)
- Karolo (nomo) - karolo (himno)
- flustro (mallaŭta parolo) - flustro (insekto)
- soleno (ceremonio) - soleno (konkulo)
- radikala (atinganta la fundamenton) - radikala (rilate al radikalo)
- vato (kotono) - vato (unuo)

Mi scias ke mi vidis pli en PIV kiuj ne estas en la vikipedia listo.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few:

- [*Kubo* and *kubo*](http://vortaro.net/#kubo) the country Cuba and a cube respectively;
- [*golfo*](http://vortaro.net/#golfo) the sport and a gulf;
- [*vato*](http://vortaro.net/#vato) cotton and the unit watt;
- [*piĉo*](http://vortaro.net/#pi%C4%89o) vulgar word for female genitals or pitch.

There are probably a couple more, but I cannot think of any others. I will edit this answer if I find any incidentally.

Comment: Both of you perfectly answered the question. I just felt it was most fair to select Tomaso’s answer as the ”correct one”, since he provided a longer list. A pity one cannot select two answers as the answer! :-)

Comment: @Bjørn Fair enough! Yes, that indeed is a pity!